# How to Get JSON Values and save them in another file in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to make an electron app.
I want to read json files (`config, messages`) and save them to their respectable places.

The Problem is that the script will save the json of the first value in a file with the name.

The script get the first value which is json and saves it but then doesn't get the next value to get the json just saves the links in a file format.

```
var allText

var adminconfigjson
var adminconfigsave

var adminmessagesjson
var adminmessagessave

var adminconfigjson = "./assets/json/adminconfig.json"
var adminconfigsave = "./bot/AdminOptions/Config.json"

var adminmessagesjson = "./assets/json/adminmessages.json"
var adminmessagessave = "./bot/AdminOptions/Messages.json"

function create_bot() {
  var json = [adminconfigjson, adminmessagesjson]
  var newjson = [adminconfig, adminmessages]
  var save = [adminconfigsave, adminmessagessave]
  var text = ""
  var i
  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log(json[i])
    readTextFile(json[i])

    function readTextFile(file) {
      var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest()
      rawFile.open("GET", file, false)
      rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
          if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < newjson.length; i++) {
              newjson[i] = rawFile.responseText
              console.log(newjson[i])
              if (newjson[i] != "") {
                for (i = 0; i < save.length; i++) {
                  var newsave = JSON.stringify(save)
                  for (i = 0; i < newjson.length; i++) {
                    if (newsave[i] != "") {
                      savefile(newsave[i], newjson[i])
                      console.log(save[i])
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      rawFile.send(null)
    }
    function savefile(filepath, content) {
      fs.writeFile(filepath, content, function(err) {
        console.log("file path" + filepath)
        if (err) {
          alert("An error ocurred updating the file" + err.message)
          console.log(err)
          return
        }
        alert("The file has been succesfully saved")
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tip #1: Simplify.  Certainly all that code / all those variables are not needed for a [mcve]?

Comment: I have updated the code took out some of the variables

Comment: You provided a lot of info, but without a lot more context, this is really hard to understand. It seems like you are trying to parse a single json string into separate files, right? Why not just use JSON.parse, get what you need, JSON.stringify it and save it where it goes?

Comment: This code is really strange. Do you realize that your for loop variables are overwriting each other in addition to completely overwriting newjson right after assigning it the first time? I would be happy to help you refactor it, but you would need to explain it much better.

Comment: @Lonster_Monster -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the code and the question could be better phrased, your intention is to read from a source and save that JSON to a destination under a new filename.

I've kept it without introducing async/await so you can follow through the same logic as you initially supplied.

The issue with the `xhr` request is that since the application is an `electron` app, you don't need to fetch, as the files are based locally on the app.

If you wish to fetch an external JSON file, say an `api` or external `FS`, then you will need to include a xhr module/call for that.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const files = [{
  source: "./assets/json/adminconfig.json",
  destination: "./bot/AdminOptions/Config.json"
}, {
  source: "./assets/json/adminmessages.json"
  destination: "./bot/AdminOptions/Messages.json"
}]

// bot reads a config 
// and then saves the content of source to destination
const create_bot = () => {

  // note: you could make a symbolic link 
  // between the data directory and the output
  // but that's up to you
  // 
  // e.g.
  // const filenames = fs.readdir(data_directory).then((error, filenames) => filenames)

  // we iterate through each file_object
  const filenames = files.forEach(file_object => {

    // read the source
    fs.readFile(file_object.source, "utf-8")
      .then((err, content) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`An error ocurred reading the file: ${err.message}`)
          throw new Error(err);
          return
        }

        // write the file
        // (destination, content, encoding) => callback
        fs.writeFile(file_object.destination, content, "utf-8")
          .then((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(`An error ocurred updating the file: ${err.message}`)
              throw new Error(err);
              return
            }
            console.log("success")
        }
    })
  })
}

create_bot();
```

Comment: I was looking at your code  it is what I am needing but for some reason when I test it says Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: I fixed it had to make the readfie part be  fs.readFile(file_object.source, 'utf-8', function (err, content) { and the write file be fs.writeFile(file_object.destination, content, function (err) {'